# Animals v.s. human mum and tamim in offering

Tags: kohen-priest, parts-of-the-body, parashas-emor

Regards animals it is said: Any [animal] that has a blemish (mum מום) you shall not offer up (Leviticus 22:20), and that it has to be  tamim (תמים - 22:21). While regards the kohanim who brought the offers also couldn't have a mum, but of whom it isn't said that they had to be tamim.

Why is it that a animal in the offering has to be tamim, but of a human in the offering this part is left out?